# button on contentOverlayView not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I cannot work this out - it should be simple.

I have:

ShowAVPlayer method

```
AVPlayerItem *video = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];
AVQueuePlayer *queue = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc] initWithItems:@[video]];
video = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithURL:url];   
[queue insertItem:video afterItem:nil];    
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:url];
self.avmovieplayer = [AVPlayerViewController new];
```

I want to add a button to my overlay - but the button is not responding :

```
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[btn setTitle:@"Do stuff" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 330, 320, 40);
[btn addTarget:self action:@selector(DoSpeech:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:true];
[self.avmovieplayer.contentOverlayView addSubview:btn];
```

Here is my `DoSpeech` which is never being called:

```
- (void) DoSpeech:(UIButton *)button {

   //DoSpeech

}
```

Comment: Why are you adding button to contentOverlayView? just add it to view. i.e, [self.avmovieplayer.view addSubview : btn];

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
[btn setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[self.avmovieplayer.contentOverlayView bringSubviewToFront:btn];
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Unfortunately not - but thanks any how ! When I tab the doStuff button avplayerviewcontroller is responding  to the tab - is it something first responder maybe

Comment: Ok I found the answer From the apple docs:
Use the content overlay view to add additional custom views between the video content and the controls.
So it looks like this: (with a bunch of other layers over your UISlider)
To make it work just change this line:
[avPlayerViewController.contentOverlayView addSubview:sliderForVolumeControl];
to this:
[avPlayerViewController.view addSubview:sliderForVolumeControl];
- See more at: http://www.mzan.com/article/34529065-uislider-added-on-avplayerviewcontroller-contentoverlayview-is-not-responding.shtml#sthash.rRHDzDiT.dpuf

Comment: its the same with a button

Comment: Good to hear @TheSnakeWizard  that you have solved your problem. Cheers.